# How to copy bricked sd card to a folder

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I have a sd card that is not working and wanted to know if it is possible to just copy everything from it to a folder. and then from there I can get the data I want out?

it shows up when writing fdisk -l, so I'm thinking it should be possible to recover it's data.

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D2E3AD64-F811-498E-9E39-6851E1B789A5

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     616447     614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2      616448     821247     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3      821248    1083391     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1083392  292954425  291871034 139,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  1937899520 1953523711   15624192   7,5G Linux swap
/dev/sda6   292956160 1937899519 1644943360 784,4G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7,3 GiB, 7822376960 bytes, 15278080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

***UPDATE***

```
jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=sdcarddataNew.img bs=4M
[sudo] password for jeggy: 
dd: error reading ‘/dev/mmcblk0’: Input/output error
1686+1 records in
1686+1 records out
7074086912 bytes (7,1 GB) copied, 539457 s, 13,1 kB/s

jeggy@jeggy-Lenovo-Z50-70:~/Desktop$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 sdcarddataNew.img 
losetup: sdcarddataNew.img: failed to set up loop device: Device or resource busy
```

And I tried to use R-Linux on the .img file and found nothing usable 
[image]

This was the best image I found: 
[image]

ps. after it was done I tried to take the micro sd card out of the micro to normal sd card adapter, but it was kinda burned and melted, so it's probably completely screwed now..

Comment: Looks like your card only contain garbage. Try [`testdisk`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk/) which is my favorite application in recovering data

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`dd(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/dd.1.html) to copy the sd card.

```
$ dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=sdcarddata.img bs=4M
```

After that, you could map the image with [`losetup(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/losetup.8.html)

```
# losetup /dev/loop0 sdcarddata.img
```

Once you have done recovering and get your files out, unmap the image (make sure you unmount it first)

```
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Comment: I'm still running the first command, and my file has gotten to 800mb, so this will probably take 8 more days to finish ... :P

Comment: it's at 6,5GB :D

Comment: Only a few more days to go :P

Comment: updated the answer, thanks for the help, but I'm just gonna give up...

Comment: There are plenty of loop devices. Run `# losetup -f` to get an unused loop device

Comment: I successfully ran "sudo losetup /dev/loop3 sdcarddataNew.img" but nothing happened? should I see a new mounted  device in Nautilus or what?

Comment: Install [`testdisk`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk/) and try to recover data from `/dev/loop3`

Comment: I only got my main harddrive to choose from: http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202015-07-29%2003:13:41.png
 And tried this: http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202015-07-29%2003:18:48.png

Comment: Detach the loop device and try to run `testdisk /path/to/image`